# How to inject a Spring bean into a hibernate custom type?

Tags: spring, hibernate

We have many Hibernate Entities with a @JoinColumn field of type Location. The location data are basically static, so we decided to cache them completely in memory.

The original plan was to replace all Location fields with a locationId field. However, we soon realized this is too much work, especially since there are Criteria queries referencing the location fields that can't be easily picked up by existing tools.

The alternative is to implement a custom Hibernate type that maps the locationIds from the database to Location objects, but there doesn't seem to be any easy way to inject the cache bean into the custom type instance.

(Our version of Hibernate does not provide the Configuration.registerTypeOverride() call, so we cannot control the instantiation of the Type instance and thus no way to inject.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case, I can subclass the PersistenceProvider for the Entity and pass the Spring context in right after the session factory has been created.